# Magnolia cms Gmail configuration?

Tags: email, configuration, gmail, magnolia

I want to be able to send emails from Magnolia CMS using a Gmail account. What are the steps to follow?

I am having authentication issue when trying to [verify the setup by sending a test email](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Mail#Mail-Verifyingsetup).

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps for dummies:

1. Back in **Magnolia**, go to your user profile and **provide an email**. That’s where the test email will be sent to (see step 7) `/admincentral#app:security:systemUsers;/:treeview:`
2. Back in your **Gmail account**: settings: **allow IMAP**
3. Back in **Magnolia**, go to the mail app: `/admincentral#app:mail:main;`
4. Add your SMTP settings (auth via SSL worked for me) as [described here](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229?visit_id=1-636117997050481062-4194544010&rd=2)

[image: Magnolia CMS: Google IMAP setup]

5. Always in **Magnolia**, try to send a test email: `/admincentral#app:mail:verify;`
6. Back in your **Gmail account**: receive that **warning email from Google** (see screenshot) & follow the link in that email to allow "less safe apps"

[image: Google's "allow less safe apps" email]

7. Back in **Magnolia**, try to send a test email again `/admincentral#app:mail:verify;`
8. Voila :)

Note: the `/admincentral*` are the url path to jump directly to the relevant section of admin central, this is only informative & hopefully will help you save time.

---

#### Resources

Magnolia CMS mail module: [documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Mail](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Mail)

[support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229?visit_id=1-636117997050481062-4194544010&rd=2](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229?visit_id=1-636117997050481062-4194544010&rd=2)

[support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en](https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en)